# crystal reports error in silverlight application on installation

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, silverlight-4.0, crystal-reports

I have pubslihed an silverlight application which has crystal reports in the IIS server it shows me the error as below could any one help me to resolve

```
Configuration Error
    Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:


Line 32:         <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 33:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 34:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 35:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 36:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
```

Comment: The biggest mistake was choosing to use SilverLight.

Answer (score 2):

Based on teh error message, it seems that the crystal report version installed on your system does not match the crystal report version you used on your code. Please double check it so that you can sync the crystal report version for your site.

Besides, there are several requirements to run Crystal Report properly:

1. Please make sure the CR version installed on the server matches the one you use on your application/website
2. Please make sure that the assemblies of the CR installed on the server are referenced correctly on your web.config
3. Please make sure you set the application pool of your application to operate under LOCAL SERVICE permission
4. Please make sure FULL TRUST mode is enabled on your operating folder
5. Please make sure crystalreportviewer and aspnet_client folders are copied to your operating folder.

I have been using Crystal Report for a while. I have also tried the latest Crystal Report for VS 2010 and initially, I experienced the problem like you do now. By following all the steps above, your CR will certainly work fine. Should you still have problems, you can consider hosting it withasphostcentral.com

Please mark this response as an "answer" if it helps you. Thanks heaps!